# Extracting area from map and making this new layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, definition-query

It is probably the most simplest thing to most people, but I am only starting out in the GIS world. I have a map of Ireland but my focus is on one particular county. I want to 'crop' the rest of Ireland out and just view my county of choice.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Which software are you using? Try going into Properties > Definition Query, then select only the polygons where County is your county of choice

Comment: I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2. Thanks, I did I got it figured out. I went into the attribute table and just narrowed down my county and created a new layer from the selected features.

Comment: Please consider providing a detailed answer on how you accomplished this.  In this way, future readers will benefit and this question can be considered resolved.

Comment: Sounds like 'create layer from selected features'. Consider also in the data frame you can supply a mask (right click on layers, select properties then go to the tab 'data frame' and specify a layer in 'Clip Options') which excludes features outside the mask from drawing and definition queries on layers to reduce the number of records drawn http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000002z000000.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [comment by @MYFamily](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128099/how-to-extract-area-from-map-and-make-this-new-layer#comment183668_128099):

> Try going into Properties > Definition Query, then select only the
>   polygons where County is your county of choice

Alternatively, consider the comment by @MichaelStimson which will mask out all layers:

> Consider also in
>   the data frame you can supply a mask (right click on layers, select
>   properties then go to the tab 'data frame' and specify a layer in
>   'Clip Options') which excludes features outside the mask from drawing
>   and definition queries on layers to reduce the number of records drawn
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000002z000000.